# Solve Recurrence Equation Problem

Tags: recurrence-relation

How we calculate the answer of following recurrence?

$$T(n)=4T\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{3}\right)+ \log^2n\,.$$

Any nice solution would be highly appreciated.

My solution is to substitute $n=3^m$, giving
$$T(3^m)=4T\left(\frac{3^{m/2}}{3}\right)+\log^2 3^m = F(m)=4F((m/2)-1)+m^2=O(m^2logm)= O(\log^2 n \log n \log n)\,.$$

Comment: Give base case ?

Comment: And is this discrete? Should it be, say, $\lfloor \tfrac13\sqrt{n}\rfloor\,$?

Comment: Dear @hanu, we have no base case.

Comment: Dear @DavidRicherby, just i know the answer is $O(log^2 n)$

Comment: @DavidRicherby The reference question does not explain how to deal with the $\sqrt{n}$. [This question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/3482/13022) may be a better target.

Comment: Dear @FrankW, i see this link, but i dont underestand how this one is solved. in my answer sheet just mentioned the final answer, not detail answer.

Comment: @MinaSimin Note that $\log^2 n \log n \log n = \log^4 n$.

Comment: @MinaSimin How do you arrive at that $O$-term?

Comment: have you taken a look here [Akra Bazzi method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method)?

Comment: yes, but it's not related in my thoutgh.

Comment: The last line in your post should be $=O(\log^2n\log\log n)$.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Careful, some people read $\log^2 n = \log(\log n)$. Splitting the terms hints in this direction, imho.

Comment: @hanu The base case is often dropped if the implicit assumption is that we are only after $\Theta$ of the solution; then, the anchors are just "some constant" since they don't impact the result. For similar reasons, the recurrence is given as sloppily as it is (not really over naturals).