# How to find ${O(T(n)=4T(\frac{n-2}{2}) +n^2)}$

Tags: recurrence-relation

In given:
$${T(n)=4T(\frac{n-2}{2}) +n^2 }$$
How can i find ${O(T(n))}$ ?

Comment: Hint : Solving $T(n) = 4T(n/2) + n^2$ is same as solving the recurrence you have written.

Comment: Firstly thank you. Secondly, can you explain why is same?

Comment: You can't just ask all questions on your exercise sheet here.

Comment: I just asked it about this post:
http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29230/solve-recurrence-equation-problem
it's not related to exercise sheet...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $S(n) = T(4n-2)$. Then
$$
S(n) = T(4n-2) = 4T\left(\frac{4n-4}{2}\right) + \Theta(n^2) = 4T(2n-2) + \Theta(n^2) = 4S(n/2) + \Theta(n^2).
$$
The master theorem tells us that $S(n) = \Theta(n^2\log n)$, and so $T(n) = \Theta(n^2\log n)$.

More generally, the statement of the [Akra–Bazzi theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method) (specifically, the $h_i$ functions) makes it clear that the small perturbation in this recurrence ($\frac{n-2}{2}$ instead of $\frac{n}{2}$) doesn't change the asymptotics of the solution. From this theorem you can derive the solution directly without guessing the substitution $S(n) = T(4n-2)$.

Comment: Thank you!! In addition, can you give motivation for how to know how to define ${"The- S(n)"}$ ?

Comment: You look for a function $f(n)$ that satisfies $\frac{f(n)-2}{2} = f(n/2)$. Given a value for $f(1)$, you can calculate $f(n)$ for all powers of 2, and if you're lucky, the function has a simple expression in terms of $n$.